# How to use (?) and (!) in Swift

Tags: ios, string, dictionary, swift

I'm new to swift and I'm having some difficulties understanding on how to use (!) and (?)

As far as I know, we can use (?) when there are instances that a variable can be nil.
And use (!) when you are 100% sure that item is not nil.

**1. Working Fine - Optionals**

```
var john:String?
john = "Is my name"
println(john!)
```

**2. Crashes on Runtime - ! must not be nil - means this is correct**

```
var john:String?
println(john!)
```

**3. Works Fine**

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject] = Dictionary()
dict["name"] = "John"
var str: String = dict["name"]! as String <--- Taking away the (!) says it's not convertible to String
```

**4. Cannot Run/Build - for me it's similar to 1.**

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject]? = Dictionary() ---error says does not have a member named 'subscript'
dict["name"] = "John"
var str: String = dict["name"]! as String
```

**5. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value**

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject] = Dictionary()
dict["name"]? = "John"
var str: String = dict["name"]! as String
```

Would be great if someone can help me understand these things. Thanks!

Comment: Considering that dereferencing a nil `Object!` causes an exception, I'd want to be more than 'pretty sure'!

Comment: I've changed the pretty sure to 100% sure. And Yes, for number two I understand that it would crash based on the definition of (!). 

But say for 5 where there is ? in the dictionary, why it says found nil when there is John on it?

Comment: @ShlbyPuerto, it is a bit misleading interpretation believing when an `!` 'marks' an ivar then that 100% cannot be `nil`. it can be. you can say only, you got the value as _already_ unwrapped, so you don't need to force unwrapping it again – but it can be `nil`, try this example for instance: `var text: String! = "hello"; text = nil; println(text)`, it prints a `nil` for you. the reason why you app can crash is you force to unwrap an optional which is `nil`, that is invalid operand.

Comment: @holex Yes, I understand that. Thanks. But I think the post is abit complicated to what I am trying to ask. But it's not about no. 2 (states the understanding is correct). I'm more complicated on 4 and 5. Where 4, for me is a bit similar to 1, but I'm sure I'm wrong that's why I need some help. For 5 to why it is nil when I assigned John on it?

Comment: @ShlbyPuerto, see my answer about 4 or 5, I'm personally not seeing any complication with them, they are just not correct. if you have further question, please let me know. :)

Comment: I don't understand why people are down voting this question. Does it  not show any research effort? Is it unclear or not useful? I don't think so. OP misunderstood the concept of Swift Optionals, so what? Asking for help when trying to understand a concept and providing code examples of what you did is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @JoJoe, _"OP misunderstood the concept of Swift Optionals, so what?"_. yes, I guess that is possible, but the reason why people may downvote is they have spent time to read and understand the concept from the documentation, which is – in my view – quite clear and explains nicely the situation in spite of that is a massive docs. :)

Comment: @JoJoe Thanks! Very much appreciated. I just needed a clear view of what it means since I couldn't understand completely to what's in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is a bit misleading interpretation believing when an `!` 'marks' an ivar then that 100% cannot be `nil`. it can be. you can say only, you got the value as already unwrapped, so you don't need to force unwrapping it again – but it can be `nil`.

try this example for instance:

```
var text: String! = "hello"
text = nil;
println(text)
```

it prints a `nil` for you.

the reason why your app can crash is you force unwrapping an optional which is `nil`, **that is invalid operand**.

---

## #4

line-by-line:

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject]? = Dictionary() // from OP
```

your `dict` is an *optional*, let us see what you are doing here:

```
dict["name"] = "John" // from OP
var str: String = dict["name"]! as String // from OP
```

you have an *optional* `dict` and you'd like to use it somehow, you have two possible ways to do it:

- **(A)** via optional chaining;
- **(B)** via forced unwrapping;

#### (A)

```
dict?["name"] = "John" // optional chaining
```

it is quite straightforward, it assigns the new value for the key `name` if the dictionary is not `nil`, otherwise the chain generously falls and nothing happens in runtime.

in perspective of this line:

```
var str: String = dict!["name"]! as String // forcibly unwrapped
```

it crashes in runtime if either the dictionary or the value for the key was `nil` (as per the first paragraph says: invalid operand to force unwrapping a `nil`), but the `str` would be `John` if the dictionary and the key *both* do valid objects.

#### (B)

```
dict!["name"] = "John" // forcibly unwrapped
```

it works like a charm and assigns the new value for the key `name` if the `dict` exists; but if the `dict` was `nil`, that is a termination point in runtime (aka crash), because `nil` cannot be unwrapped forcibly (see above).

---

## #5

line-by-line:

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject] = Dictionary() // from OP
```

your `dict` is not optional and not even `nil`, but the dictionary is literally empty, so no key does exist in it, including the `name`.

```
dict["name"]? = "John" // from OP
var str: String = dict["name"]! as String // from OP
```

the optional chaining always falls when any of the element of the chain falls – therefore no new value will be assigned in your code, but the falling happens gracefully, so you bypass the first line about assigning the new value, but the app crashes in the second line because the value does not exists and you try to force unwrapping it (see above about invalid operand).

so, you need to drop the optional chaining from the first line, if you want to assign a new value for a *non-existing* key:

```
dict["name"] = "John"
```

---

the optional chaining is useful if you would not like to change the original dictionary with adding a new key/value, but you would like to override an existing one only:

```
dict["name"] = "John"
dict["name"]? = "Jack"
```

in that case the new value will be `Jack`, because the optional chaining won't fall as the key `name` is already existing with a different value, so it can be and will be overridden; but:

```
dict["name"] = nil
dict["name"]? = "Jack"
```

the optional chaining will falls and no new value is assigned here for the key.

---

*NOTE: there would be many other things and ideas which can be told about the concept. the original documentation is available on Apple site under section [Swift Resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/).*

Comment: Thanks for these, it's a big help. As for the documentation I sometimes don't understand things on what is and what's not. That's why I posted something like this.